# Delete objects created during object construction?

Tags: c++, c++11

If objects are created during the construction of a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  std::vector < MyObject*> MyObjects = { new MyObject };
...
```

Do I need to delete the objects in the vector during the destructor?

Comment: yes, of course. unless you use smart_ptrs, which is almost always a better idea

Comment: you need except if they are referenced elsewhere of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `std::vector < MyObject*> MyObjects` contains pointers to objects. The vector assumes it does not own the objects, so it does not delete them by default.

If you want the objects to be destroyed automatically either change the type:

```
std::vector <std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> MyObjects
```

Or, delete all the pointers in the:

1. destructor
2. assignment operator
3. In the constructors, in case of an exception. If there is an exception, then without treatment, part of the vector is going to be filled with objects. Due to the exception the pointers will not be deleted, unless explicitly handled.

Using `std::unique_ptr` is usually the preferred solution, since it ensures that the memory will be freed. But that comes at the cost of no default assignment/copy constructor. You either live without assignment/copy are stay only with move semantics, or have to explicitly define assignment/copy. But that is not a big price, since with simple pointers you still have to define assignment/copy.